# No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel

Tags: android, kotlin, http, networking, ktor

Ktor can not parse response in one place. It is working for other places but for one request Ktor can not parse the data even though it is similar to other responses. Here is the Ktor implementation. I saw some similar issues while searching web but none of them worked for my case, I would be glad if you have answers.
Thank you in advance!!!

```
internal fun getHttpClient(
configurations: Configurations,
context: Context,
isMarket: Boolean,
userStorage: PrefStorage
) = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
val timeout = 30_000L
engine {
    addInterceptor(
        ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(context).collector(ChuckerCollector(context))
            .maxContentLength(250_000L)
            .redactHeaders(emptySet())
            .alwaysReadResponseBody(false)
            .build()
    )
    config {
        connectTimeout(timeout, MILLISECONDS)
        writeTimeout(timeout, MILLISECONDS)
        readTimeout(1, MINUTES)
    }
}
install(Logging)
install(DefaultRequest) {
    url(if (isMarket) configurations.marketUrl else configurations.baseUrl)
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    headers {
        val language = runBlocking { userStorage.getLanguage() }
        append("X-Bank-Application-Id", configurations.bankApplicationId)
        append("X-Bank-REST-API-Key", configurations.bankRestApiKey)
        append("Accept-Language", language)
        append("language", language)
        append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer ${runBlocking { userStorage.getToken() }}")
        if (isMarket) {
            append(
                "Accept-Location-Id",
                runBlocking { userStorage.getLocationId() }.toString()
            )
            append("client-id", runBlocking { userStorage.getCustomerNumber() })
        }
    }
}
install(HttpTimeout) {
    requestTimeoutMillis = timeout
    connectTimeoutMillis = timeout
}
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(
        Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            encodeDefaults = true
        },
    )
}
HttpResponseValidator {
    validateResponse { response ->
        if (response.status.value == 401) {
            userStorage.setToken("")
            throw ServerErrorResponse("Not authorized")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe the case where Ktor cannot parse a response in more detail?